# How do I set breakpoints using the Photran IDE in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gdb, fortran, photran

I know it sounds like a simple question, but trying to create a simple "Hello World!" application and debug with GDB doesn't seem to give me the option of creating breakpoints. Is anybody else seeing this? Is there something I'm missing?

There is a [bug recently filed in bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384187). But I want to make sure that the problem isn't just that I'm missing some necessary setting or plug-in.

**Update:** [This bug has been fixed for Juno SR2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384187).

Comment: I use Eclipse only occasionally, but I have never gotten breakpoints to work in Photran either.

Comment: I have tested setting breakpoints manually with gdb and it seems to work fine. There seems to be something wrong with the interface.

One trick I've learned is that I can place break point declarations in the .gdbinit file (i.e. "break <file name>:<line number>") and the program will break appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this problem is specific to the Juno version of Eclipse (and the corresponding PTP package).

For now using Indigo and related packages does the trick until they fix this bug.

**Update:** [This bug has been fixed for Juno SR2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384187).

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same but was able to use single Break point. In the Debug window select -->Instruction Stepping Mode, now at this moment you will see the options Toggle Break point and Toggle Line Break point active for selection. Select 'Toggle Line Break point' and you will see the break point assigned at the 'arrow pointer line' there after you can try to manually place by giving the line number in 'Run Configuration'.