# Breakpoints are not hit when debugging Fortran using Eclipse.

Tags: eclipse, gfortran

I have a problem when debugging Fortran using Eclipse (I use the gfortran compiler). I can't set breakpoints, or, more precisely, only "parallel breakpoints" type is available (the green ones). Then when I start debugging, all the program is executed (whereas I want it to stop, of course, whenever a breakpoint is hit). I'm used to programming in Matlab but have recently started learning Fortran, as it is much faster; however I got crazy with this debugging issue (Matlab is a LOT easier to debug; just doble-click to set the breakpoint and then press F5, or F11 if you want to step in).

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a bug in the IDE, see [Bug 384187](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384187). Are you using the latest Photran version? At [How do I set breakpoints using the Photran IDE in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592435/341970) it is claimed that this bug has already been fixed.

If everything works properly (which it should), debugging in Eclipse is just as easy as it is in Matlab.

Fortran has a long history in numerical computations that is why we have such a vast amount of legacy Fortran code. However, if I started learning a new programming language I would either learn C or C++.